# .prop() returns object rather than value

Tags: jquery

I'll try to make my question as simple and clear as possible. So i recently read the [`.prop()` vs `.attr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) page on the stackoverflow, and decided i'd start using `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

HTML

```
<form action="php/select.php" method="POST" class="ajax">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Show</legend>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Show Servers"/>
        </div>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="SHOW_SERVERS"/>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form.ajax").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var t=$(this);
        var form=t.serialize();
        var method=t.prop("method");
        var url=t.prop("action");//Before: t.attr("action");
        console.log(url);
    });
});
```

Here comes the weird part, when i submit that form, what it prints in the console is this

[image]

My question is then:

**Why does JQuery return an input element rather than the value of the form action property?**

**Why can `.prop()` get the value of the method attribute, but not the action attribute**

PS: I already know the input has the property `name="action"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does JQuery return an input element rather than the value of the
>   form action property?

It has got nothing to do with jQuery as such.

It is the specification of HTML itself. The controls in a form are submitted with the form and the `name` of the control becomes the property of the form. More here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name

This is different from an attribute which is on the `form` tag.

So, without even using jQuery, if you were to refer to an `input` element called `example`, you would do that as `formname.example`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jct8ksr3/

Snippet:

```js
$("form.ajax").on("submit",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log(this.example);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="php/select.php" method="POST" class="ajax">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="example" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Show Servers"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

What jQuery does is that it exposes the `attribute`s with `attr`. These return the attribute values (*of the tag*) which actually do not change from the source. However, jQuery also exposes the properties of an element (*the current values of the tag attributes included*). And because the form control names are attached as properties to the form, it will return those as well.

You may see that by just logging this in your code:

```
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Nicely explained. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The `method` attribute is not for `boolean` value. You need to use `attr()` for this. The `prop()` should be used only for setting and resetting boolean values like `disabled` or `checked`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form.ajax").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var t=$(this);
        var form=t.serialize();
        var method=t.attr("method");  // Change here
        var url=t.attr("action");     // Change here
        console.log(url);
    });
});
```

FYI, `prop()` is **not** a replacement for `attr()`. Consider this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" checked="checked" id="chkBox" />
```

Use:

```
$("#chkBox").prop("checked"); // true
$("#chkBox").attr("name");    // chkBox
```

With the same code, I guess it should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form.ajax").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this);
    var form = t.serialize();
    var method = t.attr("method");
    var url = t.attr("action");
    console.log(url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="php/select.php" method="POST" class="ajax">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Show</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Show Servers" />
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="SHOW_SERVERS" />
</form>
```

I can see `php/select.php` in the Console.

[image]

The reason why it returns the `<input />` is, as said by [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%c3%81lvaro-gonz%c3%a1lez), (I don't wanna take that credit), it is because if there's `<input name="something">`, then the `<form>`.`something` will be a property of the form. So `prop()` got confused with the same `name` and `action`.

[image]

For more information, see [named form fields become properties of parent form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name).

Comment: But it returns the form method fine, just not the form action

Comment: @ahmadalbayati Updated.

Comment: @Tushar Clarified. Kindly check.

Comment: I still don't think i get it. It works for method, method is a string, just like action. what's the difference?

Comment: I know it works. i wanted an explanation, not a fix for my codes.

Comment: @ahmadalbayati I guess I clarified you. Kindly check out this: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc

Comment: YES. Why does that happen, and why does it work with method but not with action. Just an explanation

Comment: @ahmadalbayati Er... I am not sure. Actually I am going through both the documentation and code. It is interesting to note that it says, `.prop( propertyName ) » Returns: Anything`

Comment: @ahmadalbayati I am trying it. Please hold.

Comment: @ahmadalbayati The culprit is here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/prop.js

Comment: It's worth noting that `.prop()` [accepts `Anything`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value) and [returns `Anything`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I said that in my previous comment. I was about to update the answer as same as yours. You made it first.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have already suspected, confusion comes from the fact that you've used the word "action" twice in your code:

```
<form action="php/select.php" method="POST" class="ajax">
      ^^^^^^
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="SHOW_SERVERS"/>
                           ^^^^^^
```

Since jQuery 1.6, `t.attr("action")` fetches HTML attributes exclusively  and `t.prop("action")` fetches, well, JavaScript properties. So:

- `t.attr("action")` grabs `action="php/select.php"` (that's straighforward)
- `t.prop("action")` grabs a property. Since [named form fields become properties of parent form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name), we get the corresponding `<input>`.

This is a pretty good example of why the new logic helps avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Ah!!! Man, I guessed it. But didn't strike. I was about to write the answer quoting it here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/prop.js.

Comment: so what is the difference between these `checked="checked"` and `checked`?

Comment: @Jai In what context? Whatever, we have the HTML attribute and the JavaScript property. In the case of "checked", the HTML attribute works by being present or not (its value is a **string** and is not relevant) and the JavaScript property is a **boolean**.

Comment: I know you had the answer first, but i better liked his explanation. No offense ^.^. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: This is not a speed contest, it's a collective knowledge base ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking in jQuery source code (line 8239 in jquery-1.11.3.js), you can see that the `prop` function relies (after several checks) on calling the given element field.

In your example, the element is the form and the fields you are trying to get are `method` and `action`. It returns 'post' for `method`, because `method` is a proper field of the form (the DOM object), so `form[method]` returns 'post' as expected. Now regarding `action`, there's no `action` field in the form (the DOM object), so calling `form[action]` in fact triggers an underlying mechanism that ultimately returns the first element in the form that has `action` as its `name` attribute: the `input` you see in the console.